# Gridview Control Bind DropDownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Please help me with this. I have a GridView Control on my page which contains 2 dropdownlist(University and College). University is bound at `page_load` event while College depends on the `Uninversity.selectedValue`. I have an add button which adds a new row to the grid.

The problem is when there are more then 1 rows. I am unable to figure which college to bind on `onselectedIndexChanged` event. It keeps on Binding the college of first row.

**This is what I have done so far in my SelectedIndexChanged Method**

```
    protected void drpUniversityName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRowEventArgs e1 = (GridViewRowEventArgs)e; // Gives me a casting error on this line 
        DropDownList drpUniversityName = (DropDownList)(e1.Row.FindControl("drpUniversityName"));
        DropDownList drpCollegeName = (DropDownList)(e1.Row.FindControl("drpCollegeName"));
        bindColleges(drpUniversityName,drpCollegeName);
    }
```

I need some way to get the current row's university and college.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUniversity" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                            onselectedindexchanged="ddlUniversity_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCollege" runat="server">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

and here is the c# code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            GridView_DataBind();
    }

    private void GridView_DataBind()
    {
        string[] datasource = { "1", "2", "3" };

        GridView1.DataSource = datasource;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void ddlUniversity_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow currentRow = (GridViewRow)((Control)sender).NamingContainer;

        //your code here
    }
```

Comment: Thanks `GridViewRow currentRow = (GridViewRow)((Control)sender).NamingContainer;` worked for me. This is what I needed exactly.Much Appreciated. **Thanks A lot**.